# Background color of li on hover is not working correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a specific problem with my simple horizontal navigation bar. When I set background-color for the whole ul, I get changes on hover only for text, but not for the background. I've tried to set li:hover and a:hover but everything was the same. For example, when I set a different color for background-color property (black, red...) everything is fine, but with rgba value it doesn't work on a screen bigger than 600px. I want to have the same effect on both and only set a different color makes a problem, as I see. Can someone, please, tell me where is my mistake and how can I fix it?

Here's my Code

```css
  body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: navbar;
}

.item2 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item2 ul li>a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: ivory;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid saddlebrown;
  background-color: rgb(44, 33, 30);
}

.item2 li a:hover {
  color: sandybrown;
  background-color: rgba(44, 33, 30, 0.8);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .item2 ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(44, 33, 30);
  }
  .item2 ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
  }
  .item2 ul li>a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px;
    border-right: 1px solid saddlebrown;
    background-color: rgb(44, 33, 30);
  }
  .item2 li:hover a {
    background-color: rgba(44, 33, 30, 0.8);
    color: sandybrown;
  }
```

```html
<div class="item2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Biographie</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Œuvre</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">L'homme politique</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Postérité</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have here is cause by having this style:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .item2 ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(44, 33, 30); <--- container background.
  }
}
```

its the same background so the elements will not have background `rgba()` clearly visible, I changed to `color:#CCC` so that you notice the issue:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: navbar;
}

.item2 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item2 ul li>a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: ivory;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid saddlebrown;
  background-color: rgb(44, 33, 30);
}

.item2 li a:hover {
  color: sandybrown;
  background-color: rgba(44, 33, 30, 0.8);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .item2 ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #CCC;
  }
  .item2 ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
  }
  .item2 ul li>a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px;
    border-right: 1px solid saddlebrown;
    background-color: rgb(44, 33, 30);
  }
  .item2 li:hover a {
    background-color: rgba(44, 33, 30, 0.8);
    color: sandybrown;
  }
```

```html
<div class="item2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Biographie</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Œuvre</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">L'homme politique</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Postérité</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand. When I made an inversion of colors everything looks better. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Apply hover effect to anchor tag if possible

a:hover{}

Answer (score 1):

Your selector of the :hover is too weak: it should be analog to the none hover:

```
.item2 ul li > a {}
.item2 ul li > a:hover {}
```

This works for me well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <style>

    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .item2 {
      grid-area: navbar;
    }

    .item2 ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .item2 ul li > a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
      color: ivory;
      padding: 5px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid saddlebrown;
      background-color: rgb(44, 33, 30);
    }

    .item2 ul li > a:hover {
      color: sandybrown;
      background-color: red;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
      .item2 ul {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: rgb(44, 33, 30);
      }

      .item2 ul li {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
      }

      .item2 ul li > a {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 12px;
        border-right: 1px solid saddlebrown;
        background-color: rgb(44, 33, 30);
      }

      .item2 ul li > a:hover {
        background-color: yellow;
        color: sandybrown;
      }
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="item2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Biographie</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Œuvre</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">L'homme politique</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Postérité</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes it works, I've already tried it, but when I set "background-color: rgba(44, 33, 30, 0.8);" I have a problem on screen bigger than 600px.

Comment: the :hover must be  behind the a, not behind the li.